# Check if mouse is over div element, even if overlapped

Tags: typescript, dom-events, svelte, onmouseover, overlapping

I'm making a chess game using svelte and ts, and I want to detect which square the mouse is over, so it can be the targetSquare of the currently dragged piece. In other word, I say: if square is hovered, then set targetPosition to its position. However, The onmouseenter event is not fired for squares that are under a Piece element. (because the piece is completely overlapping the square). How do you fire the onmouseenter event for these squares? (I don't want to use "pointer-events: none" for the chess piece because I need the drag events for it)
The piece and square components are divs.

```
// in the Square svelte component

square.onmouseenter = () => {
PieceLogic.hoveredSqr = index;
}

// in the Piece svelte component
piece.onmouseup = () => {
setPosition(PieceLogic.hoveredSqr);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mouse over events are not fired during drag at all. You will have to use drag-specific events like `dragenter` and `dragleave`.

I would recommend just disabling pointer events during the drag only. If the piece is within the tile hierarchically, this could be done by just setting a class on the tile on `dragenter`. If they are not hierarchically related, you will have to communicate that in code.

A simple example where the hierarchy exists:

```html
<script>
    let hovered = false;
</script>
<div class="tile" class:hovered
     on:dragenter={() => hovered = true}
     on:dragleave={() => hovered = false}>
    <div class="piece" draggable="true" />
</div>

<style>
    .tile.hovered .piece { pointer-events: none; }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e0eb3a101067496bb5973f7228c24129?version=3.55.1)

(If you are not using the drag & drop API, the same approach of disabling the pointer events conditionally should work as well.)